# Pytorch delivering results with [0, 0, ..., n, 0] for multi-dimensional output (Abalone Data Set)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, pytorch-dataloader

Trying to build a simple model to reconstruct the features of the Abalone (or really just return the averages) based on the gender (which I have detonated 1=I, 2=F, 3=M) and the amount of rings. Problem is that it always returns some fashion of [0, 0, n, n, n, 0, 0] or [0, n, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] or some combination where at least 1 of the terms are 0, depending on the random start.

```
raw_data = np.genfromtxt("abalone.csv", delimiter=',', dtype=float, encoding=None)
ring_data = raw_data[1:, 8]
body_data = raw_data[1:,0:8]


body_train, body_test, ring_train, ring_test = train_test_split(body_data, ring_data, test_size=.05, random_state=26)

raw_data = np.genfromtxt("abalone.csv", delimiter=',', dtype=float, encoding=None)
#after spending time fighting with this over the raw data, I went into excel and used =IF(A1="M", 3, IF(A1="F", 2, 1))
ring_data = raw_data[1:, (0,8)]
body_data = raw_data[1:,1:8]

#print(body_data)

body_train, body_test, ring_train, ring_test = train_test_split(body_data, ring_data, test_size=.025, random_state=26)

class Data(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, body, rings):
        self.y = torch.from_numpy(body.astype(np.float32))
        self.X = torch.from_numpy(rings.astype(np.float32))
        self.len = self.X.shape[0] 
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.X[index], self.y[index]
   
    def __len__(self):
        return self.len
    
batch_size = 64 #random number

#load the data 
train_data = Data(body_train, ring_train)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=train_data, batch_size=batch_size)

test_data = Data(body_test, ring_test)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=test_data, batch_size=1)


class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.layer_1 = nn.Linear(2, 7)
       
    def forward(self, x):
        result = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.layer_1(x))
        return result 
    
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda")
else: 
    device = torch.device("cpu")
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 300
fail = True
failCounter = 0

while(fail):
    loss_values = []
    counter = 0
    model = NeuralNetwork().to(device)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    loss_fn = nn.L1Loss()
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        counter += 1
        if(counter % 5 == 0):
            print(loss_values[counter])
        if(counter > (5) and loss_values[counter] > 0.5):
            failCounter += 1
            print("fail " + str(failCounter))
            print("Restarting")
            break
        
        for X, y in train_dataloader:
            # zero the parameter gradients
            X = X.to(device)
            y = y.to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
 
            # forward + backward + optimize
            pred = model(X)
            loss = loss_fn(pred, y)
            loss.backward()
            loss_values.append(loss)
            optimizer.step()
        if counter == num_epochs:
            fail = False

print("Training Complete")

import itertools
y_pred = []
accurate = 0
total = 0
x_test = []

model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    for X, y in test_dataloader:
        outputs = model(X.to(device).float())
        y_pred.append(outputs[0])

    for num in range(len(y_pred)):
        
        print(ring_test[num])
        print(y_pred[num])
        print(body_test[num])
        print("------")
```

The output looks like:

```
[ 3. 11.]
tensor([0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.4442, 0.2243, 0.0000])
[0.63   0.48   0.185  1.21   0.53   0.2555 0.322 ]
------
[ 3. 12.]
tensor([0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.4666, 0.2398, 0.0000])
[0.58   0.465  0.16   1.0345 0.315  0.26   0.3635]
```

But it depends on the random state, it can look like

```
[1. 6.]
tensor([0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0655, 0.0000])
[0.24   0.185  0.07   0.0715 0.026  0.018  0.025 ]
------
[3. 5.]
tensor([0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.1410, 0.0000])
[0.28   0.205  0.1    0.1165 0.0545 0.0285 0.03  ]
```

I want to just return the average that you would expect of an Abalone with a given gender/age. I tried to use .flatten() on the data but wasn't sure how to use it correctly/if that was the answer.